# How to rightly join broken line from Opencv lines function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to replicate what I have on the **example image** using the opencv lines function. I have been able to draw the lines on the target image but the lines are broken,

I want to align the broken lines so that they can appears as the example image, please how can I achieve this.

Below is my output image with the broken lines.

**Example image**

[image: 1]

**Output Image**

[image: 2]

My sample code.

```
results = hr['matchedPoints1'].values.tolist()
results2 = hr2['matchedPoints2'].values.tolist()

for i in zip(results, results2):
    color = tuple(np.random.randint(0,255,3).tolist())
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = i
    print( (x1, y1), (x2, y2))
    cv2.line(img1, (x1,y1), (x2,y2),(255,255,255), 2)

    
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
```

Lines extracted from the two Matchedpoints below

```
(89, 368) (108, 343)
(39, 384) (57, 354)
(109, 532) (54, 492)
(685, 320) (711, 348)
(625, 292) (647, 308)
(625, 306) (646, 331)
(176, 466) (139, 442)
(156, 350) (118, 330)
(269, 318) (232, 308)
(269, 301) (229, 293)
(632, 209) (659, 225)
(587, 138) (617, 147)
(578, 80) (609, 86)
(571, 128) (601, 135)
(388, 155) (390, 155)
(370, 88) (371, 90)
(364, 159) (366, 158)
(211, 189) (199, 181)
(193, 240) (198, 234)
(194, 264) (199, 253)
(103, 292) (106, 271)
(135, 331) (112, 308)
```

**Target images**

[image]
[image]

Below is my cameraMatrices and MatchedPoints.

MatchedPoints1

```
89.6214953271028,368.64953271028
39.3785046728971,384.200934579439
109.957943925234,532.53738317757
685.359813084112,320.799065420561
625.546728971963,292.088785046729
625.546728971963,306.443925233645
176.948598130841,466.742990654206
156.61214953271,350.705607476636
269.060747663551,318.406542056075
269.060747663551,301.658878504673
632.724299065421,209.546728971963
587.266355140187,138.967289719626
578.892523364486,80.3504672897196
571.714953271028,128.200934579439
388.686915887851,155.714953271028
370.742990654206,88.7242990654206
364.761682242991,159.303738317757
211.640186915888,189.210280373832
193.696261682243,240.64953271028
194.892523364486,264.57476635514
103.976635514019,292.088785046729
135.079439252336,331.565420560748
```

MatchedPoint2

```
108.593312597201,343.442457231726
57.2340590979786,354.192068429238
54.8452566096425,492.742612752722
711.765940902022,348.220062208398
647.268273716952,308.804821150855
646.073872472784,331.498444790047
139.647744945568,442.577760497667
118.148522550545,330.304043545879
232.811041990669,308.804821150855
229.227838258165,293.277604976672
659.212286158632,225.196734059098
617.408242612753,147.56065318818
609.047433903577,86.6461897356141
601.88102643857,135.616640746501
390.47200622084,155.921461897356
371.361586314153,90.229393468118
366.583981337481,158.310264385692
199.367807153966,181.003888024883
198.173405909798,234.751944012442
199.367807153966,253.862363919129
106.204510108865,271.778382581648
112.176516329705,308.804821150855
```

Comment: You are drawing the lines wrong. `MatchedPoints1` are for the first image. `MatchedPoints2` are for the second image. You are picking points from both these lists and drawing in the first image, hence the unexpected output. You need to draw lines **among** points in `MatchedPoints1` on the first image. Likewise for the second image

Comment: Also change the line drawing function to `cv2.line(img1, (x1,y1), (x2,y2),color, 2)`

Comment: @JeruLuke The **MatchedPoints1** has only two value for the coordinate of the lines, but the lines function requires four values `(x1,y1), (x2,y2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each set of points are unique to the corresponding images.

I have shown how to obtain the visualizations for the first image using `MatchedPoints1`:

```
MatchedPoints1 = [(89.6214953271028,368.64953271028),
(39.3785046728971,384.200934579439),
(109.957943925234,532.53738317757),
(685.359813084112,320.799065420561),
(625.546728971963,292.088785046729),
(625.546728971963,306.443925233645),
(176.948598130841,466.742990654206),
(156.61214953271,350.705607476636),
(269.060747663551,318.406542056075),
(269.060747663551,301.658878504673),
(632.724299065421,209.546728971963),
(587.266355140187,138.967289719626),
(578.892523364486,80.3504672897196),
(571.714953271028,128.200934579439),
(388.686915887851,155.714953271028),
(370.742990654206,88.7242990654206),
(364.761682242991,159.303738317757),
(211.640186915888,189.210280373832),
(193.696261682243,240.64953271028),
(194.892523364486,264.57476635514),
(103.976635514019,292.088785046729),
(135.079439252336,331.565420560748)]


img = cv2.imread('house.png')
img2 = img.copy()

for e, i in enumerate(MatchedPoints1):
  color = tuple(np.random.randint(0,255,3).tolist())
  if (e < (len(MatchedPoints1) - 1)):
    img2 = cv2.line(img2, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), (int(MatchedPoints1[e+1][0]), int(MatchedPoints1[e+1][1])), color, 2)
    img2 = cv2.circle(img2, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), 5, color, -1)
```

**Result:**

[image]

> The same can be done for the second image using `MatchedPoints2`.